# Convert PFX certificates with "Enable Certificate Privacy" to without Certificate Privacy so I can view them without installing

Tags: windows, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate

I have a bunch of PFX files that I can't view when I `Right Click > Open` them as the `PFX` files were created with the `Enable Certificate Privacy` option.

How do I convert them so that I can view the certificates and yet keep just the private key encrypted with a password? OpenSSL? I do not want to install and export them without certificate privacy individually.

**With Enable Certificate Privacy**

[image]

[image]

**Without Enable Certificate Privacy**

[image]

**This is the OpenSSL command I use:**

```
openssl.exe pkcs12 -export -out out.pfx -inkey private.key -in cert.txt -certfile cert_bundle.txt -password pass:123456
```